# Issue with SASS/CSS for Foundation 5 using Compass

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm having a problem with Foundation 5's recommended SASS installation.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

I followed the brief tutorial only a week or so ago and had no problems. Everything seemed to run OK and looked OK.

Over the course of the next few days I was making amendments to the project I am working on but only put the changes (CSS) into a `custom.css` file. I was wanting to ensure my client was happy with my proposed design before getting into the guts of SASS.

This evening I came to make the changes to SASS. I ran `compass watch` before I made any changes and I was immediately met with:

`write stylesheets/app.css`

This totally screwed up my `index.html` despite not having made any changes. The `app.css` file is only a fraction of the original size (~750 lines vs. ~8,500) and as a result the page is pretty much loading as raw HTML with no useful CSS - there's not even a hint of any styling on `body` for example.

After deciding to re-install from scratch I'm still no better off and running into very much the same issue.

According to Foundation:

> **app.scss** 
>   Here you can determine what stylings will be in your project.
>   **By default all of Foundation is imported**, but you can deactivate and
>   select specific components you want to import or add your custom Sass
>   here.

When I first installed Foundation, it was all imported as the default styles loaded for my `index.html`. It was acting how Zurb described it would. Now it only seems to grab some default styles but not the whole thing and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

**Update:** A friend cloned my repo and had no issues whatsoever. I've done the same and ran into the same issue again - must be something to do with my environment.

**Further update:** `compass watch` is only compiling two of the Foundation files, `_icon-bar.scss` and `_visibility.scss`. It seems to be pulling completely arbitrary lines even within those files, so something in them is not right either. It does not pull anything from anywhere else. There's a couple of pastebin links in the comments on the answer below.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: My BitBucket repo https://bitbucket.org/andrewtanner1987/dev.napiercountryfestival.co.nz This is how it looked previous to this evenings antics i.e before running compass watch and just relying on custom.css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just learning Foundation 5 with Sass but your issue and the CSS output is looking how mine was compiling out as well, with lot's of comments and no CSS being pulled into the HTML..

[This thread on the Foundation Forums](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18630-scss-compiles-but-resulting-css-file-incomplete) really helped me.  Seems like the latest Sass and Compass wasn't working properly??  Not sure the details but the suggestion from Szabesz to uninstall the latest Sass and Compass and install slightly older ones worked:

```
to uninstall:
sudo gem uninstall compass 1.0.0
sudo gem uninstall sass 3.4.0

to reinstall old versions:
sudo gem install sass --version 3.2.9
sudo gem install compass --version 0.12.7
```

Comment: We have a winner! Thank you so much. I had recently installed the new Google Web Starter Kit which prompted me to install Sass 3.4.0 so that's where my problem came from. Thank you very much, my weekend will now be a productive (as opposed to frustrated) one!

Comment: I've gotta repair the dent in my desk after dealing with this.  Thank you.

Comment: Annnd....there went the last 4.5 hours of my life. Thank you so much! I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was going on!!!

Comment: Sass 3.2.9 doesn't support maps, though. If you want maps, you can install version a 3.3.x version, as long as it's earlier than 3.4. For example, I installed Sass 3.3.14 and Compass 1.0.0.rc.1 - this combination supports maps, and works with Foundation 5. See Scott Rod's comment here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18630-scss-compiles-but-resulting-css-file-incomplete#edit_comment_15996

Answer (score 0):

What's in app.scss what ever is listed in there will be output as css in app.css.

@import "settings"
@import "foundation"

Is the default.

Comment: Yep. I did mate. Exactly how it says on the link I posted up. If I hadn't, I expect I wouldn't even get as far as this problem.

Comment: Here's scss/app.scss as it stands right now, fresh install http://pastebin.com/Ei1bX2NE and here is what is being compiled as a result of that stylesheets/app.css http://pastebin.com/AQEmTbuv

Comment: Obviously, a lot of the app.scss is commented out, but as the Zurb website says, it should compile the default Foundation styles anyway, as per bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss (I presume!)