# Using compass - css styling not applying foundation.css

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Installed Foundation 5 with Sass a couple of days ago. But, after:

- foundation new test_grid
- cd test_grid
- compass watch

files, directories created by watch...

open index.html and there's no styling. (I also tried 'compass compile' and 'compass watch', but no changes.

The config.rb that compass uses shows:

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

And the app.scss shows:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

Looking at stylesheets/app.css it seems that the foundation.css file hasn't been imported.

Any ideas of what's going on? Could be a totally newbie problem...knocked my head against the wall and googled ad nauseam.

---

Based on a suggestion, I reinstalled compass, but still get the same.
Compass seems to be okay when watching:

```
emily@emily:~/sites/test_grids(master*)$ compass watch
>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
directory stylesheets
write stylesheets/app.css
```

and when I modify bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss (insert p {font-size: 10rem;} it shows:

```
modified bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss
write stylesheets/app.css
```

The refreshed index.html font size changes, but again, no foundation.css styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this problem too and found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25560150/3990944

The latests Sass and Compass are not compatible. Try uninstalling and installing older versions. Worked for me. Details are in the post above.

Comment: Thank you! Almost ready to give up on it, but this worked! Will send a note to Foundation to let them know about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make changes in the _settings.scss or app.scss, not the files located in Bower components. See file descriptions here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass-files.html

How to use
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/using-sass.html

Comment: You're right about what file(s) to use for customizations, but my main problem is that the default foundation.css styles aren't applying to  index.html. -- When I look at the stylesheets/app.css file, the class stylings from foundation.css aren't listed. --  The only way to see the styling is to add a <link rel="stylesheet"...> in the index.html that points to the foundation.css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
sudo gem uninstall compass 1.0.0

sudo gem uninstall sass 3.4.0

sudo gem install sass --version 3.2.9

sudo gem install compass --version 0.12.7
```

This method worked for me